# Long exact sequence for compact manifolds with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the cotangent bundle $T^*S^2$ equipped with the [Eguchi-Hanson metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eguchi-Hanson_space). Since the metric is ALE and the cone at infinity is $\mathbb R^4/\mathbb Z_2$, we can define a compact manifold $D$ which is the contraction of $T^*S^2$ such that $\partial D=\mathbb RP^3$.

Now we have the following long exact sequence for $(D,\partial D)$,
$$
H_{2}(\partial D) \rightarrow H_{2}(D) \rightarrow H_{2}(D,\partial D) \rightarrow H_{1}(\partial D) \rightarrow H_{1}(D).
$$
Since $H_2(\partial D)=H_2(\mathbb RP^3)=0$ and $H_1(D)=H_1(T^*S^2)=0$, we have
$$
0 \rightarrow H_{2}(D) \rightarrow H_{2}(D,\partial D) \rightarrow H_{1}(\partial D)\rightarrow 0,
$$
and hence
$$
H_{2}(D,\partial D)=H_{2}(D) \oplus H_1(\partial D)=\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2.
$$
However, by the [Lefschetz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_duality), $H_2(D,\partial D)=H^2(D)=\mathbb Z$.

Where did I make a mistake in this argument?

Comment: Is $D$ orientable?

Comment: @PaulFrost Since $D$ is a retraction of $T^*S^2$, so it is simply-connected and hence orientable.

Comment: Yes, you are right! But then the mistake must be that the short exact sequence $0 \to H_2(D) \to H_2(D,\partial D) \to H_1(\partial D) \to 0$ doesn't split. In fact, it will be equivalent to $0  \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\times 2}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}  \to \mathbb{Z} _2 \to 0$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I see. Thanks.